# Unable to connect to FTP server using "FTP Connection Manager"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to setup an SQL agent job to use my SSIS package. The package contains an FTP task that is failing. I'm getting the following error in both the job history and logging that I've setup (Log gives no other detail...):

> "Unable to connect to FTP server using "FTP Connection Manager"

I've tried setting up the SSIS package with the ProtectionLevel of EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. Going into the SQL job and entering the password. All the tasks run fine except for the FTP task.

I then tried setting up the SSIS package with the ProtectionLevel of DontSaveSensitive. I then setup a configuration file. Manually entered the password into the DTSConfig file. Chose the configuration file in the configurations tab of the step setup. But I'm still getting the same error when running the job.

The package runs fine when ran in visual studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have been into similar situations. FTP in SSIS is very flaky. Create a `.bat` file and use a command line task to call the `.bat` file. It works really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall wasn't set up correctly.  Once I got the network admin to let port 20 through, all was working well.

I ended up sticking with the "DontSaveSensitive" and using a config file to make deployment easier through multiple environments.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that you are able to connect FTP server through windows explorer, and then try three things

For Package:
1- Package Protection Level= EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey
[image]

For FTP Connection Manager:
2-Server Port= 21
3-UsePassiveMode= False
[image]

Comment: I was getting the same error with protection level set to encrypt all with password and passive = false.  I modified my connection manager to passive mode = true and this solved the problem.  Other details are: package is in sql server 2012 ssis catalog, uses SSDT 2012 for IDE.  Plus one because your suggestions helped me find a solution.